# Javascript - Puppeteer variable not actually being filled with data

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm making a test discord bot as a quick intro to JS coming from c++, and I'm having difficulty with
puppeteer. I got it to go to the website, but I can't get it to read the text and/or put it into a variable. All that gets printed is "null".

````
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const bot = new Discord.Client();


const token = '********************************************************';
const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Successfully Logged In');
})

bot.on('message', async msg=>{

    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'hello':
            msg.reply('Hello Friend!');
            break;

        case 'stats':
            let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
            let page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/' + args[1], {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
            console.log(page.url());

            var level = await page.$('trn-defstat__value');
            //let wins =
            //let losses =
            //let winPercent =
            //let kills =
            //let deaths =
            //let kd =
            //let headshots =

            await page.waitFor(1000);

            await msg.reply('```Player:   ' + args[1] + '\n' + 'Level:   ' + level + '```');

            break;

        case 'args1debug':
            msg.reply(args[1]);
            msg.reply("debugControl");
            break;


    }
})


bot.login(token);
````

Comment: `trn-defstat__value` is not a valid CSS selector

Answer (score 0):

I think the selector isn't good. There is no element with the name
'trn-defstat__value'.

Here is a list for your selector:
[css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Maybe you need to select an element and get an attribute from this element afterwards. Then you should try _element.getAttribute():
[getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

I strongly suggestto use the full page.evaluate() function in combination with console.log() to debug your problem. Remember when you use console.log() inside the evaluate function the terminal inside your browser (F12) will show the message.